# MySQL query between three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables student, role, student-role(only has student id and role id). I want to return role(in role table) by checking the student name(in student table).

I tried:

```
select role from role rr 
join student-role sr on sr.role-id=rr role-id 
join student ss on sr.student-id=ss.student-id
where ss.name="xxx"
```

My tables are:

```
Role
Role-id      | Role          |
-------------+---------------+
1            | admin         |
2            | whatever      |


Student
Student-id   | name          |
-------------+---------------+
1            | aaaaaaaa      |
2            | bbbbbbbb      |

Studnet-role
id           | Role-id       |student-id    |
-------------+---------------+--------------+
1            | 1             |2             |
2            | 2             |1             |
```

Can anyone tell me if this is correct?

Comment: What was wrong with the query you tried

Comment: Never include '-' within a table/column identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks along the right lines.

I'd simply modify it to start with `student` and join to the other tables from there:

```
SELECT r.role
  FROM student s
    INNER JOIN `student-role` sr ON sr.`student-id` = s.`student-id`
    INNER JOIN role r ON r.`role-id` = sr.`role-id`
  WHERE (s.name = "xxx")
```

Of course, if a `student` has more than one `role`, you are going to return multiple rows with this query.  You may not be expecting that.

Incidentally, I'd recommend against using hyphens (`-`) in your column names.

**EDIT**

I added backticks to the column names following @Strawberry's comment.  Of course `student-id` is not a valid column name without backticks.

Comment: And one more question ,how can I insert a user into the database into three tables? insert into student ,then get student id? then insert into student-role with student id and role id?

Comment: @DavidShi That is correct, however I'd suggest adding a further question if you need more detail about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified column name and table to understand clearly.

```
create table role (role_id integer, role varchar(100));
create table std (std_id integer, name varchar(100));
create table std_role (id integer, role_id integer , std_id integer);


insert into role (role_id, role) values(1, "admin");
insert into role (role_id, role) values(2, "whatever");

insert into std (std_id, name) values(1, "aaaa");
insert into std (std_id, name) values(2, "bbbb");

insert into std_role (id,role_id,std_id) values(1,1,2);
insert into std_role (id,role_id,std_id) values(1,2,1);


SELECT role.* FROM std_role
INNER JOIN std ON (std.std_id=std_role.std_id)
INNER JOIN role ON (role.role_id=std_role.role_id)
WHERE std.name = 'aaaa';
```